# How can I pass a list of selected packages to a service in Android?

Tags: java, android, performance, listview, sharedpreferences

I am trying to setup a whitelist in my app. I have a service setup that will trigger another service when it detects that a certain app had started. I have a package picking activity that builds a nice list with checkboxes. When I select a checkbox, I want to add that selected app to the "whitelist". I then want my service to check against that whitelist while it runs. I cannot get my whitelist to pass its list over to my service. Here is the package list I am using...

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // this has to be done before any preferences are populated!
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesMode(Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences2);

    // get a list of launchable apps
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent main = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

    main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> launchables = pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);

    Collections.sort(launchables,
            new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

    PreferenceCategory targetCategory = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("targetCategory");
    targetCategory.setTitle(getString(R.string.settings_header));

    for (ResolveInfo info : launchables) {

        // get app info
        ActivityInfo activity = info.activityInfo;
        ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
        final String pkgName = name.getPackageName();
        CharSequence appName = info.loadLabel(pm);

        CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPreference = new CheckBoxPreference(this);

        // set the data
        checkBoxPreference.setKey(pkgName);
        checkBoxPreference.setTitle(appName);
        checkBoxPreference.setSummary(pkgName);
        checkBoxPreference.setIcon(info.loadIcon(pm));

        // add to category
        targetCategory.addPreference(checkBoxPreference);
    }
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    Preference pref = findPreference(key);
    CheckBoxPreference cbtp = (CheckBoxPreference) pref;
    final String pkgName = key;
}
```

}

Here is the service that I am using to check for the running app. I need to check if the running app has been selected from that list. If the current app has been checked, I want my service to run. I have the service running fine, and the list builds great. I just cant seem to get them to work together.

```
                @Override
            public void run() {
                SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                 vibenabled = mySharedPreferences.getBoolean("vib_preference", false);
                 pkgName = prefs.getBoolean(pkgName, false);
                ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                Log.d(TAG, "Its running");   

        String lastPkg = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
       if (selectedPkg.equals(lastPkg)) {
              startService();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a binder:**

- Your activity binds to the service for the duration of the activity running.
- Your service returns a custom binder object to the activity
- Your activity can then directly or indirectly access the services whitelist via the binder object (i.e. make yourself a *getWhiteList()* or *addToWhiteList()* method)

Or you can use an intent via custom broadcast receiver:

- Implement a broadcast receiver in your service
- Send intents to that receiver whenever a checkbox is clicked.
- Put the selected checkbox type (i.e. pkgname of the app) as extra in the intent

Or you can use an intent via the [startService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) method of the service:

- Put the selected checkbox type (i.e. pkgname of the app) as extra in the intent
- Use the intent to call start the service
- You should get the intent including its extras passed along to the *onStartCommand* method

Or (cheap solution):

- Write the checkbox selection into preferences
- Upon changing a checkbox start the service again
- Put some code in [*onStartCommand*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) that checks for changes and updates the list.